# Wordpress theme options Menu

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu, settings-api

I am struggling from last 1 Hour couldn't find why the menu is not appearing WordPress admin.

```
<?php

function wpt_add_theme_page() {
    add_theme_page(
        __('Theme Options','wpsettings'),
        __('Theme Options','wpsettings'),
        'edit_theme_options',
        'wptsettings',
        'wpt_theme_options_page'
    );

}

function wpt_theme_options_page() {
    echo "Hello";
}


/*---------------------------------------*/
/* Enqueue Theme Styles */
/*---------------------------------------*/

function wpt_theme_styles() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_theme_styles' );

?>
```

Is there any syntax error that I couldn't find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook your function to the `admin_menu` action:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpt_add_theme_page' );
```